# Is there a way in Windows to prevent an opening application from taking control of the keyboard/mouse and displaying on top of other windows?

Tags: windows, application-launch

Is there a way in Windows to prevent an opening application from taking control of the keyboard/mouse and displaying on top of other windows?

I cannot stand when I have my browser open and am reading a news story while the application is deciding to load and then all of a sudden in the middle of reading a sentence up pops this application.  This is even more annoying if you are in the middle of typing while an application is loading and then all of a sudden you are typing half a word into another application.

So just to reiterate I would like to be able to open applications behind open windows and not have the application take over keyboard/mouse control.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't always work (depends on the app), but you can try launching the app minimized.  Right-click and choose 'Properties' on the shortcut and in the RUN box select MINIMIZED.